# How I solve key issue for Git lab CI CD?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How solve key error in gitlab CI/CD using deploy yml file

My yml code like this:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/using-multiple-aws-accounts-for-deploy/7242

[image]

Comment: Have you actually installed it? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html

Comment: @Dennis V , But in my yml file how add?

Answer (score 0):

So you might be passing the aws creds in a different variable name. The variable names should be

- AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
- AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

In your yml file and in project settings go to cicd ---> Variables. You can set access key, secret key based out on environment. To do that you need to add environments section your yml template. so corresponding keys will be fetched

[image: variables]

Comment: @veera so you do not need to run `aws configure` as part of your job - you can provide AWS credentials using environment variables, explainer in this answer.